# Program name of this buckling modeling

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, statics, buckling

My instructor sent this solving with program that I don’t know the name , does anyone know the name of the program ?

[image]

Comment: Is this Euler’s formula ???

Comment: What do you mean yes , but I want the program name

Comment: What do you mean yes?

Comment: That's an interesting series of comments, lacking punctuation and reasonable grammar for clarity. Razi's comment might be read as "What do you mean? Yes, this is Euler's formula, but I want the name of the program displayed in the screen capture." Lee's comment appears to validate the confusion presented by Razi's comment.